# How does uniswap call the approve function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, evm

I am trying to build a no-code tool for users, I want to be able to transfer tokens on the user's behalf.

anytime I call the `IERC20(token address).approve`function, my metamask does not a return a screen like the attached image and the `IERC20(token address).transferFrom` function does not execute.

Approve function

---

tps://i.stack.imgur.com/NfyMC.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `approve()` function from within your contract would just approve tokens to be spend **from your contract address** - not from the user.

You need to invoke MetaMask popup **from your frontend app** - not from the contract.

Either using their [request](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-request-args) method, requesting a transaction to the token contract, with `data` field of the `approve()` function and its arguments.

Or with more high-level approach: Creating a frontend instance of web3js, ethers.js, or whichever library you prefer, connecting to the `window.ethereum` local provider, and then invoking the `approve()` function on the token contract from here. This will also open the MetaMask popup windows asking the user to sign the transaction.